# Django Serialization With Normalized Models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am having trouble Serializing my following Django models using DRF. This is my following modal code:

````
```python
class Project(models.Model):
    project_number = models.CharField(unique=True, null=False, max_length=25)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(default="N/A", blank=False, max_length=10)
    date_updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.CharField(default="N/A", blank=False, max_length=10)
    project_closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Network(models.Model):
    network_number = models.CharField(unique=True, null=False, max_length=25)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(default="N/A", blank=False, max_length=10)
    date_updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.CharField(default="N/A", blank=False, max_length=10)
    estimated_completion_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    network_completion = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Project_Network(models.Model):
    project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name="project", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    network_id = models.OneToOneField(Network, related_name="networks", on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Part(models.Model):
    part_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    part_category = models.CharField(
        null=False, 
        blank=False, 
        max_length=9,
        choices=[
            ('A', 'A'),
            ('B', 'B'),
            ('C', 'C'),
        ]
    )


class Network_Part(models.Model):
    network_id = models.ForeignKey(Network, related_name="parts", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    part_number = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    part_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    equipment_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```
````

This is the way these modals fit together:

- Project Model - holds project information (highest level of info)
- Network Model - a Project can have multiple networks associated with it (think of Networks as sub projects)
- Project_Network Model - the relationship between Projects and Networks.  A Project can have multiple networks associated with it, however a Network can only be associated with One Project (hence the One-To-One Field)
- Part Model - a set list of parts which can be associated with a Network
- Network_Part Model - the relationship between Networks and Parts. A Network can have multiple parts associated with it.

My desired following output is:

```
[{
    "project_number":1,
    "date_created":<date>,
    "created_by":<user id>,
    "updated_by":<user id>,
    "date_updated":<date>,
    "project_closed":<boolean>,
    "networks": [{
        "network_number":1,
        "date_created":<date>,
        "created_by":<user id>,
        "updated_by":<user id>,
        "date_updated":<date>,
        "network_completion":<boolean>,
        "parts":[
            {
               "part_number":1,
               "part_quantity":1,
                "equipement_code":1,
             },
             {
                "part_number":2,
                "part_quantity":1,
                "equipement_code":2,
             }
         ]

    }]

}, ]
```

I am struggling with how to obtain this format using DRF. I think I am getting hung at the Project_Network and Network_Part tables.

It could be the way I have my models setup, any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
Here is my current approach to the serialization:

```py
class PartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     
    class Meta:
        model = Network_Part
        fields = '__all__'


class ProjectNetworkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    parts = PartSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project_Network
        fields = '__all__'


class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    networks = ProjectNetworkSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'
```

The ProjectSerializer works if the 'parts' line is commented out in the ProjectNetworkSerializer. It gives:

```
    [{
        "project_number":1,
        "date_created":<date>,
        "created_by":<user id>,
        "updated_by":<user id>,
        "date_updated":<date>,
        "project_closed":<boolean>,
        "networks": [
            "network_number":1,
            "network_number":2,
            "network_number":3,
        ]
    }]
```

**FINAL SOLUTION**
As pointed out by @IainShelvington, changing around my models fixed said issue.
As relationship is One-to-One between Project and Network, and it makes sense to have a direct Network -> Project ForeignKey. This allowed me to refine my models to be more direct:

```py
    class Project(models.Model):
        project_number = models.CharField(unique=True, null=False, max_length=25)
        date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        created_by = models.CharField(default="N/A", blank=False, max_length=10)
        date_updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
        updated_by = models.CharField(default="N/A", blank=False, max_length=10)
        project_closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    class Network(models.Model):
        network_number = models.CharField(unique=True, null=False, max_length=25)
        project_id = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name="networks", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        created_by = models.CharField(default="N/A", blank=False, max_length=10)
        date_updated = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
        updated_by = models.CharField(default="N/A", blank=False, max_length=10)
        estimated_completion_date = models.DateField(null=True)
        network_completion = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    class Part(models.Model):
        part_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        part_category = models.CharField(
            null=False, 
            blank=False, 
            max_length=9,
            choices=[
                ('A', 'A'),
                ('B', 'B'),
                ('C', 'C'),
            ]
        )


    class Network_Part(models.Model):
        network_id = models.ForeignKey(Network, related_name="parts", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        part_number = models.ForeignKey(Part, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        part_quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        equipment_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Very simple solution, thanks again @IainShelvington.

Comment: Could you please show your approach for the `serializer classes`?

Comment: Have edited the OP

Comment: Why the `Project_Network` model? A `ForeignKey` directly from `Network` -> `Project` would achieve what you want and simplify things a bit?

Comment: @IainShelvington you are right. The Project_Network was product of an old requirement where a Network could be One to Many with Projects.  However this has changed (hence the One-to-One restriction), and it makes sense to have a direct Network -> Project ForeignKey.  I have changed it over and works like a charm. Thanks!